# highcharts, possible bug setting tooltip formatter and html?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have set these options:

```
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<table style="text-align: center"><tr><td>{point.x:%Y-%b-%e}</td></tr><tr><td>Price: {point.y}</td></tr></table>';
                  }
```

but I still get this output.

[image]

If I use:

```
               tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true,

                    headerFormat: '<table style="text-align: center"><tr><td>{point.x:%Y-%b-%e}</td></tr><tr><td>Price: {point.y}</td></tr></table>',
                    pointFormat: '',
                    footerFormat: '',
                    valueDecimals: 2
                },
```

then I get:

[image]

However, when I zoom out to All or a 10 year period, I get the same output as first.

[image]

There seems to be a bug when around 3 years are used.

**Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates the error:**

https://jsfiddle.net/3Ld2zmum/2/

**Zoom out to All**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In formatter you should use reference to point object and [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat)

```
formatter: function () {
            return '<table style="text-align: center"><tr><td>' + (Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%b-%e', this.x)) + '</td></tr><tr><td>Price: ' + this.y + ' </td></tr></table>';
        },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3Ld2zmum/3/

Comment: Great, that worked wonders! But the tooltip headerFormat, pointFormat seems to be a bug though, right? But this will do fine for me!